# is there a method to merge two data frames by country and gender?

Tags: r, dataframe

I got two data frames, for example:

one is for males:

```
country weight
Spain      80
Germany    70
Italy      60
```

and the other one is for females:

```
country weight
Spain      65
Germany    70
Italy      60
```

Now I want to merge them and make them look like that:

```
country gender   weight
Spain         m      80
Spain         f      65
Germany       m      70
Germany       f      70
Italy         m      60
Italy         f      60
```

I hopes the example makes My problem clear.

Thank you

Comment: add a column to each existing dataframe with gender, then `rbind` them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
countries <- c("Spain", "Germany", "Italy")

weights <- c(80, 70, 60)
dfMale <- cbind(data.frame(countries), data.frame(weights))
dfMale$Gender <- "m"


weights <- c(65,70,60)
dfFemale <- cbind(data.frame(countries), data.frame(weights))
dfFemale$Gender <- "f"

newdf <- rbind(dfMale,dfFemale)
```

Comment: I tried that, but then I get a data frame with 5 columns.

Comment: You should use `dfMale <- data.frame(countries, weights)` instead of this `cbind()` construct.